# OpenID Connect for Azure Active Directory

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, openid-connect

I am trying to use this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect_windows_aad

But, when I install it, it says something is missing, but does not state what is missing.  Per the requirements, I also have OpenID Connect installed, but this does not seem to help.  Here is a screen shot of the error:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what is missing?  Is this not compatible with Drupal 8?